# Scala: omit brackets on nullary fn call with an implicit parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

I have the following:

```
object POS {
  def apply()(implicit f: Foo): Int = ???
}
```

And I can access it via `POS()` in my code. Is there any way of modifying this so that the brackets are not needed, i.e. I can write `POS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely can't just write `POS`, because it refers to the singleton object `POS` of type `POS.type`. However, you can omit the parentheses when calling it with `POS.apply` if you declare `apply` with implicit argument list only.

Even better, define `pos(implicit f: Foo)` function somewhere, then you can call it by just writing `pos`:

```
trait Foo {
  def foo: String
}
implicit object DefaultFoo extends Foo {
  def foo = "default..."
}

object POS {
  def apply(implicit f: Foo): Int = f.foo.size
  def pos(implicit f: Foo): Int = f.foo.size
}

println(POS.apply) // this works

{ 
  import POS._
  println(pos) // also works
}
```

A more obscure way to achieve a similar effect would be to define an implicit conversion from `POS.type` to `Int`, which takes an implicit `Foo` and invokes `apply` on `POS`:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

implicit def convertPosToInt(p: POS.type)(implicit f: Foo): Int = p.apply(f)

println("POS used in `Int` position: " + (2 * POS + 3))
```

(replace `p.apply(f)` by `p.apply()(f)` if you want to use the last three lines with your definition; this version works with my definition above).

The issue with implicit conversion from `POS.type` to `Int` is that it still has to be in a position where an `Int` is required for a conversion to occur. No conversion will take place if you use `POS` as a stand-alone statement.